# EWS.FindItems returns more items than expected from the Inbox folder?

Tags: email, exchangewebservices

In the Inbox folder, I only have 5 emails (4 unread as illustrated, and one already read).

[image: **Inbox Folder**]

Plus, in each of the search folders such as *Unread mails*, *Follow-ups*, etc. I have many many emails (over 1,000), and the oldest is dated of 2011 (date/time received).

When performing a [**FindItems**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.exchangeservice.finditems(v=exchg.80).aspx), I end up finding an even older email for which the `DateTimeReceived` property is worth 2004-08-15?

The only other thing I can think of is that using the **FindItems** method also gets the emails from the archived ones, could it be?

**getInboxItems**

```
private FindItemsResults<Item> getInboxItems() {
    var inboxFolderId = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox
                                    , mailboxConfiguration.MailboxName);
    var allItems = new ItemView(int.MaxValue) {
        Traversal = ItemTraversal.Shallow
        , PropertySet = new PropertySet(EmailMessageShema.DateTimeReceived
            , EmailMessageSchema.LastModifiedTime)
    };
    var foundItems = Service.FindItems(inboxFolderId, allItems);
    return foundItems;
}
```

This returns about 40 emails, and among them is found the oldest outdated email of 2004, which I can't find anywhere in any of the mailbox folders while accessing it through Outlook.

Short question is: **What happens?**

I can't find anything on the subject over the Internet.

> **UPDATE**

After further investigation, the code sample provided is proven unguilty as per these simple steps:

1. Select the Inbox folder, right-click and click Properties

[image: **Inbox Properties**]

2. Inbox Properties, in the General tab, click "Display the number of all items" (may differ from the actual English version, since I have translated myself as I thought it could be in English)

[image: **Display All Items**]

3. Now back  to the Inbox folder, we may see that there are actually that many items.

[image: **Inbox folder total count of items**]

So it seems that my code is correct, and although this total count reports to 35, when this Inbox folder is selected, I only see the five above-mentioned emails.

I thought this could have been due to archived items, and I have been confirmed that archived emails are moved to an external archive tool and deleted from Exchange, which leaves me clueless.

Comment: `Boite de reception` is inbox? (Before I go an further, may just be my language barrier). (Quick google means "Box of reception" so it makes sense, but still want to verify).

Comment: @BradChristie: Yes, in French 'Inbox' is translated by 'Boîte de réception'. =)

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be private items causing the issue.

Private items are invisible to others than the user who made these items private, and are still part of the items contained in the inbox folder.

Once proven to be the private items, one could:

1. authenticate himself to the [**OWA**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outlook_Web_App)

   [image: **OWA Authentication**]
2. click on his name to open the drop down list and input the mailbox to access

   [image: **OWA Access target Inbox**]
3. once accessed, one could see the old items and consider to delete them

Once all these items were deleted, everything was back to normal and the **EWS.FindItems** reported the right number of items, as it had always done.

So the problem really was in the inbox on the Exchange-side of the medal, not on the [**EWS**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877045(v=exchg.140).aspx) side.